# WMI Enumerate Win32_GroupUser with friendly output

Tags: c#, account, wmi-query

I'm trying to enumerate all existing groups on my local machine.

That's what I tried using wmi :

```
string _class = "Win32_GroupUser";
string namespace = "\\\\.\\ROOT\\cimv2";

ManagementClass _class = new ManagementClass(namespace + ":" + class );    

foreach (ManagementObject _object in _class.GetInstances())
{
    richTextBox1.AppendText((_object["GroupComponent"].ToString()));
}
```

Output example :

> \DESKTOP-2MSGC9J\root\cimv2:Win32_Group.Domain="DESKTOP-2MSGC9J",Name="Utilisateurs
>   du journal de performances"

In this output only the group name `Name="Utilisateurs du journal de performances"` is important to me.

**Is a way to do a wmi query that only return that element in this `_object` ?**

Another `foreach` with `_object` maybe.

Answer (score 0):

I find a dirty way using `substring` after getting my object from wmi.

```
foreach (ManagementObject _object in _class.GetInstances())
{
    string groups = _object["GroupComponent"].ToString();
    int i = groups.LastIndexOf('=') + 1;
    string groupsName = groups.Substring(i);
    richTextBox1.AppendText(groupsName + "\r\n\r\n");
}
```